# Ignore "This Workbook Contains Links to Other data Sources"

Tags: vba, excel

I am opening a file in VBA and want to ignore the above message after my file opens through the code. That is I don't want to update the file and want to continue running the code . How can I do it? I am opening multiple file and I need to wait for every file to display that, instead I thought I can do it through code.

```
filter = "Text files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
Caption = "Please Select the a file"
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)
If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)
```

Application.displayAlerts=False does not work for this. Is there anyway to manage it? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606970/how-to-open-excel-workbooks-without-the-message-the-workbook-contains-links-to-o?s=1|1.4140

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908372/how-to-suppress-update-links-warning

Comment: @Joe Even after using 
"Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False"  I am still getting message like This workbook has some links missing. "Continue or Edit" Any help on this please

Comment: Do you still have `Application.displayAlerts=False` in your code or did you take it out when you put in `Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False`? I would expect a combination of the two lines to get around the warning. (Don't forget to turn displayAlerts back on at the end of the macro). That said, Excel provides that warning for a reason - it might be worth checking through the offending workbook and fixing any broken links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
   Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

End Sub
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158276/turn-off-msg-for-update-links-for-excel-spreadsheet-upon-opening)

Comment: Even after using "Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False" I am still getting message like This workbook has some links missing. "Continue or Edit" Any help on this please

Comment: Did Joe's answer to your question solve the problem?